# how to filter inputs before sending it to a xmlhttp request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mojo

I have following two input boxes which type is "tel". maxlength is set to 10.
now, 
if user insert one or both number less than of length 10, then the alert should display about wrong number.
if one number is of exact length of 10 digit and other is not, then only accept the full length number and setting other to null.

```
<input type="tel" maxlength="10" />
<input type="tel" maxlength="10" />
```

now, if both input are not of length 10, the alert should be there, 
if one is of length 10 and other is not, the alert should be there like rejecting small no and continue with full length no of 10 digit.
if both no are of 10 digit, the alert should be, send both nos to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This

```
<input type="tel" maxlength="10" id="First" />
<input type="tel" maxlength="10" id="second"  />
```

Javascript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fst= $("#First").val().length;
var scd= $("#second").val().length;

if(fst==10 && scd==10){

alert("Please enter 10 chracters");

} else if(fst==10 && scd!=10){

$("#second").val('');

} else if(fst!=10 && scd==10){

$("#first").val('');

}


</script>
```